# How do I retrieve the data input from a scanner to use in a method?

Tags: java, methods, java.util.scanner

Basically I have to write a program that uses data that was inputted by the user and put it in a mathematical formula so it spits out an answer. The formula has to be created as a method. This is what I have so far. When I run the code it lets me input a number, but when I do that the program does not output anything and it just finishes running.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Namek {
    static int myMethod(int radius) {
        return ((radius * radius) * (22/7));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Radius");
        String radius = keyboard.nextLine();

    }

    private static void myMethod() {
    }
```

Comment: You question should how to convert a String to an `int`  **and** how to pass values to a method **and** research about integer division

Comment: In main you store your input in a String radius, which is a local variable. You never use radius after you read from your keyboard so what do you expect as output? Insert: System.out.println(""+radius); after String radius =keyboard.nextLine(); or call a reasonable method and pass radius as an parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the method passing the radius as parameter of the method. You can check https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_methods.htm
,this link to see how to create and call methods with parameters.

I think what you wanted to do is the following:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Namek {
        static int myMethod(int radius) {
            return ((radius * radius) * (22/7));
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter Radius");
            int radius = Integer.valueOf(keyboard.nextLine());
            int area = myMethod(radius);
            System.out.println(area);
        }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Below is what you were trying to do I think

```
public class Formula {
        static int myMethod(int radius) {
            return ((radius * radius) * (22/7));
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter Radius");
            int radius = Integer.valueOf(keyboard.nextLine());
            float output = myMethod(radius);
            System.out.println(output);
        }

}
```

Comment: I changed the float to an Int and changed the formula all together to what I needed it to be and it worked. Thanks!